# SVN to Git: Keep only trunk content with "basic" history

Tags: git, github, git-svn

**Background:**

I am migrating to Git a large SVN repository with 40.000 revision and 20+ GB of data.
I have got my repository fetched from SVN by running `git svn fetch` with the following .git/config settings:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
ignore-paths = ^[^/]+/(?:branches|tags)  <--- note ignoring tags and branches
url = https://svn_server/repos/my_repo
fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

As it can be noticed by the config settings above, `branches` and `tags` have been ignored as I just want to migrate the contents of `trunk`. Git-svn fetch also retrieved `branches` and `tags` directories to keep merging history.

At this point the `remotes/git-svn` branch contains:

```
repo/
--branches
--tags
--trunk
```

**Goal:**

What I want is to just have in my Git repository the contents of `trunk`, removing branches and tags, and keeping only history of existing files as I have no need to revert back to any branch, and I don`t need to see or revert any deleted file.

My first attempt was to rewrite history removing branches folder with the following command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch branches"
```

After about 48 hours running I killed the process.
I know I have a big amount of data, but this amount of time seems unreasonable to me so I guess I was not in the right direction.

By keeping only history of existing files I believe I could reduce my repository size from 20 GB to less than 1 GB, and then be able to upload it to Github.

**Question:**

Is there a way to clone only `trunk` contents to a new Git repository and keep only history of files in `trunk` with no reference to removed files or removed branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just clone the trunk and only the trunk:

```
git svn clone http://svn_server/repos/my_repo/trunk
```

Note that I point directly to trunk and do not use the `-s` option.

Comment: Thanks Mykola! I should have done that. All docs of git svn say I should point to the root of the repository so I did.
As I already have a git repository with everything I need - and more - I am trying to find a way to "fix"that by moving the contents of trunk to the root of the repository but without losing commit history. Any ideas?

Comment: It is probably possible, but would be a big of magic of subtree merge or alike. I'd expect you to save yourself much time and hassle by simply re-importing from svn anew in a clean way.

Comment: For the records: it's possible to achieve what I wanted using
`git filter-branch -f --tree-filter myFilterScript`

Git filter-branch is a very slow command, so would take more time than re-import.
Accepted Mykola's answer as this is the most cost effective approach.
Thanks Mykola!